# Create pdf file after PHP form submit

Tags: php, jquery, pdf

It is possible to create a pdf file after a PHP form has been submited?
I need to print an order details after a php form is submited.

At this time i have a small jquery script that allows to print page that it prints only html content the php variables not.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btnPrint").printPage();
});
```

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Did you Google your request?

Comment: i have searched of course an found only fpdf , i am looking into it right now also..

Comment: Well, simply said, just return a PDF document from the script that processes the order after submission. The user can then print it if he so desires...

Comment: There are more than fpdf, keep looking ;-) I sometimes spend 3 days on Google. Yeah, I know... but I have a hard head.